# Fill up an array with integer by using a range

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a numbered array from 0 to 10. I need to fill up the array by pre defined ranges. For an instance I have an object like `start=5` and `end=2`. In this case the array should be filled with `1s` from 5th position and 1 position(incl. 5) forward. Like,

```
let numArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

I tried using `numArray.fill(1, 5, 1)`. But this giving me all `0s` only. Any alternative ways to do this in JS? The array is already defined and need to do multiple updates such as start=1 end=2, start=3 end=4

Comment: Why would it start at `5` if you say `start=8`?

Comment: `.fill(1, 5, 1)` means "fill the array starting at index 5 and ending at index 1 with the value 1", so it does not make sense. Perhaps you mean `.fill(1, 5, 6)`, which does make sense.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a well-defined [mre] we with clear criteria for success so we're all on the same page.  Right now it looks like all the numbers (except `0` or `1` I guess) are random and unrelated to the desired output (why would `end` be less than `start`? what's `5` doing? what's `8` doing? etc etc)

Comment: Mistake. It should be 5. not 8. Edited.

Comment: Hmm, but `end` is still less than `start`.  Maybe that's the number of elements?  And then "start=1, end=2, start=3, end=4" means what?  And you're not using 0-based indexing apparently?  By default when people say "position" in an JS array they generally mean the zero-based index, not a one-based index.  Again, I would hope to either see a well-defined [mre] here which clears all this up, *or* an explicitly written set of unambiguous criteria.

Answer (score 1):

`fill()` it with `0` before you call `fill` to set the `1`'s.

Second argument is `start`, third is `end`, so in your example you'll need `.fill(1, 4, 6)` to fill index `4 and 5` with `1`'s

```js
let arr = Array(10).fill(0).fill(1, 4, 6);

console.log(arr);
// [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Comment: Ah OP starts at one more index, changes the values. Thanks.